# Use Taylor Series Expansion in Calculating Integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to approximate this integral:
$$
I = \int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - bx}}\ln \left( {{a_1}{e^{ - {b_1}x}} + {a_2}{e^{ - {b_2}x}}} \right)dx} 
$$
where $b,{a_1},{a_2},{b_1},{b_2} > 0$ and $b_2>b_1$.
Here is my answer:

We can observe that there exists a constant $c$ so that if $x>c$, then $\frac{{{a_2}}}{{{a_1}}}{e^{ - \left( {{b_2} - {b_1}} \right)x}} \in \left( {0,1} \right)$; and if $0 \le x \le c$, then $\frac{{{a_1}}}{{{a_2}}}{e^{ - \left( {{b_1} - {b_2}} \right)x}} \in \left( {0,1} \right]$. Actually the value of $c$ is: $$c = \frac{{\ln \left( {{a_1}/{a_2}} \right)}}{{{b_1} - {b_2}}}$$
Using the Taylor Series Expansion $\ln \left( {1 + y} \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}\frac{{{y^n}}}{n}}$ with $y \in \left( {0,1} \right)$, we obtain:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
I =  - \left( {\ln {a_1} - {b_1}} \right)\frac{{{e^{ - bc}}\left( {b + 1} \right)}}{{{b^2}}} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}}}{n}\int_c^\infty  {{e^{ - bx}}{{\left( {\frac{{{a_2}}}{{{a_1}}}} \right)}^n}{e^{ - n\left( {{b_2} - {b_1}} \right)x}}dx} } \\
 - \left( {\ln {a_2} - {b_2}} \right)\frac{{\left( {1 - {e^{ - bc}}} \right)\left( {b + 1} \right)}}{{{b^2}}} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}}}{n}\int_0^c {{e^{ - bx}}{{\left( {\frac{{{a_1}}}{{{a_2}}}} \right)}^n}{e^{ - n\left( {{b_1} - {b_2}} \right)x}}dx} } \\
 =  - \left( {\ln {a_1} - {b_1}} \right)\frac{{{e^{ - bc}}\left( {b + 1} \right)}}{{{b^2}}} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}}}{n}{{\left( {\frac{{{a_2}}}{{{a_1}}}} \right)}^n}\frac{{{e^{ - \left[ {n\left( {{b_2} - {b_1}} \right) + b} \right]c}}}}{{\left[ {n\left( {{b_2} - {b_1}} \right) + b} \right]}}} \\
 - \left( {\ln {a_2} - {b_2}} \right)\frac{{\left( {1 - {e^{ - bc}}} \right)\left( {b + 1} \right)}}{{{b^2}}} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}}}{n}{{\left( {\frac{{{a_1}}}{{{a_2}}}} \right)}^n}\frac{{1 - {e^{ - \left[ {n\left( {{b_1} - {b_2}} \right) + b} \right]c}}}}{{\left[ {n\left( {{b_1} - {b_2}} \right) + b} \right]}}} \\
 =  - \frac{{\left( {b + 1} \right)}}{{{b^2}}}\left[ {\left( {\ln {a_1} - {b_1}} \right){e^{ - bc}} + \left( {\ln {a_2} - {b_2}} \right)\left( {1 - {e^{ - bc}}} \right)} \right]\\
 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}}}{n}\left( {{{\left( {\frac{{{a_2}}}{{{a_1}}}} \right)}^n}\frac{{{e^{ - \left[ {n\left( {{b_2} - {b_1}} \right) + b} \right]c}}}}{{\left[ {n\left( {{b_2} - {b_1}} \right) + b} \right]}} + {{\left( {\frac{{{a_1}}}{{{a_2}}}} \right)}^n}\frac{{1 - {e^{ - \left[ {n\left( {{b_1} - {b_2}} \right) + b} \right]c}}}}{{\left[ {n\left( {{b_1} - {b_2}} \right) + b} \right]}}} \right)} 
\end{array}
$$
Since $\frac{{{a_2}}}{{{a_1}}}{e^{ - \left( {{b_2} - {b_1}} \right)c}} = \frac{{{a_1}}}{{{a_2}}}{e^{ - \left( {{b_1} - {b_2}} \right)c}} = 1$, we get
$$
\begin{array}{l}
I =  - \frac{{\left( {b + 1} \right)}}{{{b^2}}}\left[ {\left( {\ln {a_1} - {b_1}} \right){e^{ - bc}} + \left( {\ln {a_2} - {b_2}} \right)\left( {1 - {e^{ - bc}}} \right)} \right]\\
 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}}}{n}\left( {\frac{{{e^{ - bc}}}}{{\left[ {n\left( {{b_2} - {b_1}} \right) + b} \right]}} + \frac{{{{\left( {\frac{{{a_1}}}{{{a_2}}}} \right)}^n} - {e^{ - bc}}}}{{\left[ {n\left( {{b_1} - {b_2}} \right) + b} \right]}}} \right)} 
\end{array}
$$
Is that result converged?

Comment: You've made a mistake somewhere. $I$ should not depend on $x$, but the expression in the last line does.

Comment: Always exercise caution when attempting to use a power series to solve an improper integral. You can ordinarily get away with such tricks in the event that the bounds of integration are finite, for instance, because an analytic function is the uniform limit of its power series on any compact interval. To do the same for an improper integral might require a truncation argument.

Comment: Also, the series you wrote down (incorrect as it may be, since it should not depend on the integration parameter) does not converge unless $a_1 = a_2$, as otherwise either of the terms $(a_1/a_2)^n$ or its reciprocal will blow up geometrically, and the decay you have in $n$ is only like $n^{-2}$.

Comment: I edited my answer to be clearer and fixed the typos. Those 2 Taylor Series are definitely converged. But it is not sure for the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitution and repeated integration by parts yields
$$
\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-kx}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{n!}{k^{n+1}}
$$

Assume $b_1\le b_2$ and $|a_2|\le|a_1|$, but not both equal, then
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty e^{-bx}\log\left(a_1e^{-b_1x}+a_2e^{-b_2x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-bx}\left(\log(a_1)-b_1x+\log\left(1+\frac{a_2}{a_1}e^{-(b_2-b_1)x}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\log(a_1)}{b}-\frac{b_1}{b^2}+\int_0^\infty e^{-bx}\log\left(1+\frac{a_2}{a_1}e^{-(b_2-b_1)x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\log(a_1)}{b}-\frac{b_1}{b^2}+\int_0^\infty\left(\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac1k\frac{a_2^k}{a_1^k}e^{-(b+k(b_2-b_1))x}}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\log(a_1)}{b}-\frac{b_1}{b^2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac1k\frac{a_2^k}{a_1^k}\frac1{b+k(b_2-b_1)}\\
\end{align}
$$
where the series in red is derived from the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$.